# how to use a xgboost model to make predictions from predictors without having the response value

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have created a XGBoost model in python and now I want to use it to make predictions to on a completely new database. the problem is my new database has all my input variables (features) but it does not have the target values.

in other words, I want my model to predict the response value and tell me based on the input variables, what would each sample for their target value?

Comment: This is not a problem; in fact, this is exactly why we make ML models in the first place - wouldn't be of any real value if they could only be applied to datasets where we already knew the answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

As your model is already trained, you don't need target. You just want to predict them.

Let's say `_model = ... your fitted XGBoost model` and that `df2` is your new database with only your features.

```
df2['Predicted_target'] = _model.predict(df2)
```